# Given joint density of ${(X, Y)}$, how to prove that ${X}$ and ${Y}$ are Gaussian random variables.

Tags: probability-distributions

Assume that ${(X, Y)}$ has joint density ${ c e^{-(1+ x^{2})(1+ y^{2} ) } }$, where ${ c }$ is properly given. How can we prove that ${X}$ and ${Y}$ are Gaussian random variables, but that ${(X, Y)}$ is not a Gaussian vector.

Comment: Just check that the joint density does not have the form of a bivariate normal density. The marginals can be found by integration.

Comment: There seems to be something seriously wrong. The marginals are nor normal. Did you perhaps say joint density instead of joint characteristic function?

Comment: Yes, I mean the joint density. Could you please show how to calculate the exponential integral? I tried to do that but got stuck.

Comment: The marginals are not normal, the conditional distributions are. Recheck the exercise.

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/184414/119261

Comment: Very helpful stuff. Thanks!